# Getting NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI while JQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery

I am using JQuery Ajax.

Below is the **JQuery Code:**

```
 $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://stackoverflow.com/Login.aspx",  // Send the login info to this page
        data: str,  
        success: function(result)
        {  

           //$("#loginDetails").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
           // {  

             // Show 'Submit' Button
            $('#loginButton').show();

            // Hide Gif Spinning Rotator
            $('#ajaxloading').hide();  

            var resLength = $.trim(result).length;

            if(resLength!=0)
            {

                var arr = result.split(",");
                var fname = arr[0];
                var lname = arr[1];
                var activeCardNo = arr[2];
                var multipleTier = arr[3];
                var activeStatus = arr[4];
                var access = arr[5];

                 if(access!='' && access!='undefined') // LOGIN OK?
                 { 

                     $('.validateTips').hide();
                    var login_response = '<div id="logged_in">' +
                     '<div style="width: 350px; float: left; margin-left: 80px;">' + 
                     '<div style="width: 40px; float: left;">' +
                     '<img style="margin: 22px 0px 10px 0px;" align="absmiddle" src="system/images/ajax-loader.gif">' +
                     '</div>' +
                     '<div style="margin: 24px 0px 0px 10px; float: right; width: 300px;">'+ 
                     "You are successfully logged in! <br /> Please wait while you're redirected...</div></div>";  

                    $('#loginButton').hide();
                    $('#closeBtn').hide();
                    $('#divMember').text(fname +' '+ lname);
                    $('#spnSkywardsNo').text(activeCardNo);
                    $('#spnTierStatus').text(multipleTier);
                    $("#ui-dialog-title-skywardsLogin").text(getDataFromResourceFile('pleaseWait'));

                    $('#divSuccessLogin').html(login_response);
                    $('#divSuccessLogin').show();
                    $('#loginDetails').hide();
                    //$(this).html(login_response); // Refers to 'status'

                    // After 3 seconds redirect the 
                    setTimeout(closeDialog, 3000); 

                 }  
              }
            else// ERROR?
             {  
                 var login_response = getDataFromResourceFile('InvalidUsername');
                 $('.validateTips').html(login_response);
             }

     //});  

     }  

    });
```

the above code works perfect if I am going for **HTTP** request, say for example if I am on **http://stackoverflow.com** and have above call to my login page i.e. **http://stackoverflow.com/login.aspx** works fine, but when I go for **HTTPS** request for example **https://stackoverflow.com/login.aspx** then it is giving **"NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI"**, please suggest how can I fix this issue!

Comment: Even if you solve that 'problem', this code would have the burden of the `same origin policy`. It would only work from your `firebug` / `dev tools` console.

Comment: can you please explain it little more and how can I achieve above functionality, please suggest

Comment: you cannot make an ajax request to a foreign domain. All datatypes except `json-p` are prohibited. You can find tons of information here on SO about that topic.